# Is it possible to transfer the balance of a contract from another contract?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix, contract-deployment, contract-debugging

```
contract A{

address public seller; 


function A(){
    seller = 0xdd870fa1b7c4700f2bd7f44238821c26f7392148;
 }

function transfer_from_B(address b){

 seller.transfer(b.balance);//ERROR
}
}

 contract B{
   function deposit() payable{
 }

 }
```

I get an error when I try to transfer the balance of contract B from Contract A. Is it not possible to do that?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to do. Are you trying to transfer the balance of B to A (seller)? If yes, you have to do that in contract B - you can't *pull* balance like that. You are saying you try to transfer 'balance of contract B from contract A' which makes no sense.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen I want to transfer the balance of contract B to an ethereum address which is the seller. The seller is available in contract A.

Comment: @LauriPeltonen do u mean it is not possible to transfer the ether of one contract from another contract? Please explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution 1**

To accept a payment transfer to a smart contract you need to override the default function `function ()` and make it `payable`, so it would accept ethers.

```
function () public payable {}
```

**Solution 2**

Otherwise you can directly call the function `deposit` and add the value amount you want to transfer to that function.

```
seller.deposit().value(b.balance);
```

---

**Edit: misunderstanding.**

A smart contract can't send its balance on behalf of another contract. You will need to build a transfer function on smart contract B and call it from A.

```
contract A{

    address public seller; 

    function A(){
        seller = 0xdd870fa1b7c4700f2bd7f44238821c26f7392148;
 }

    function transfer_from_B(address b){
        b.transferBalance(seller)
    }
}

 contract B{
    function transferBalance(to) { // add modifier onlyA
        to.transfer(this.balance);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I do not want to deposit to a contract. I want to transfer the balance of contract B to an ethereum address that is available in Contract A.

Comment: Edited my answer. sorry for that misunderstanding

Comment: what is to in function transferBalance of contract B? is it the ethereum address I want to transfer to

Comment: That a function to transfer the contract balance (B) to an ethereum address. You can't do it directly from A. So A has to call B to do the transfer.

Comment: I just tried it. It executes successfully, but I cannot see any change in the ether of the receiver. Why is that happening?

Comment: Is there any fund in B? What's the balance of B?

Comment: it was 50 ether. I just tried again with 10 and 5 and 50 again ether and it worked perfectly!! .. maybe I did something wrong!! THANKS A LOT! I was stuck for daysss literally!

Comment: Cool. Glad it worked. However, do not forget to implement a modifier to only let contract A to transfer the B balance. Otherwise anybody could siphon the contract...

Comment: How do I create a modifier that allows contract A .. is it also using msg.sender?